# Is there a map editor for Dawn of War: Soulstorm?

Tags: dawn-of-war-soulstorm

Is there a map/level editor for Dawn of War: Soulstorm? I want to launch my own campaign to conquer the galaxy, and the ability to defeat some enemy strongholds would be excellent. I know there is an editor for the original Dawn of War (and also Dark Crusade), but Soulstorm changes and adds so much to the base game that the editor is worthless, and I can't find a Soulstorm one on Google.

Comment: @CloseVoter - This isn't a 'Shopping Recommendation' question, it's [Asking if a game-related-product is available, at all, anywhere, for anyone](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8389/28182), which are considered on-topic as per the meta linked above, and more recently discussed here: [Is asking about the existence of a soundtrack considered a “game rec”?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10856/28182)

Answer (score 2):

Speaking purely officially, there is no Official Dawn of War: Soulstorm map editor.

However, there are many resources (some of which are quite old) that speak about modifying and adding to the tools found within the Dark Crusade version. While I can't offer an answer to how to do that, I can offer a link to the website where that answer may lie.

[Relic News Forums](http://forums.relicnews.com/showthread.php?53579-Mission-Editor-Guide)

Hopefully in the future someone will find this answer and be able to provide further information.